# SQL Server database sync with another database table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables. The 1st table is just a normal table in a database inside SQL Server. The 2nd table is also a table in a database except that it belong to SharePoint 2007 and is not known even though one can go to the SharePoint site to see that it belong to a SharePoint Form library.

My question is how to auto-sync these two tables together? (At anytime, the two table must contain the same information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can synchronize databases with [SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).

Best Regards

Comment: Actually I was looking for a SharePoint list <== sync with ==> a table in a SQL Server database but anyway, thanks for the help.